# Path and query parameters validation in WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2

```
 <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/code">
    <inSequence>
        <property expression="get-property('uri.var.number')" name="uri.var.number" scope="default" type="STRING"/>// this is the property to store the value 
        <call> 
        <endpoint> //calling the endpoint
        <http method="GET" uri-template="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/{​​​​​​uri.var.number}​​​​​​"/> 
        </endpoint>
         </call>
        <respond/>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence/>
</resource>
```

This is Path param validation i am trying to do.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the requirement and what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Also an ESB version would be useful.

Comment: Hi @Athiththan Same like JSON validation schema i am doing for path and query param validation.

Comment: Are you trying to validate the values that are passed with customization? or are you expecting an out-of-the-box solution to validate them? Can you give more elaboration on the use-case and requirement with samples?

Comment: @Athiththan <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/code">
    <inSequence>
        <property expression="get-property('uri.var.number')" name="uri.var.number" scope="default" type="STRING"/>// this is the property to store the value 
        <call> 
        <endpoint> //calling the endpoint
        <http method="GET" uri-template="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/{​​​​​​uri.var.number}​​​​​​"/> 
        </endpoint>
         </call>
        <respond/>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence/>
</resource> This is the code where i am trying to do validation for path param

Comment: @noName, it is still unclear to me what you are trying to achieve. What I understood is that you wanted to extract the `uri.var.number` and passing it to the HTTP Endpoint. Did you want to know how to extract those? Or wanted to do perform something else?

Comment: @Athiththan I want to do validation of uri.var.number. If uri.var.number is not passed while executing i need some response back saying that number is not passed like json payload validation.

Answer (score 1):

The requirement is to send an error response if the `uri.var.number` property is empty. We can add a Filter mediator as following to validate and then perform the required actions.

Given below is a sample mediation sequence block to filter and respond back with a JSON error response if the property does not exist

```xml
<filter source="boolean(get-property('uri.var.number'))" regex="false">
    <then>
        <!-- respond back with an error message -->
        <payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>{"error": "missing number"}</format>
            <args></args>
        </payloadFactory>

        <!-- respond mediator to respond back to the client -->
        <respond />
    </then>
    <else>
        <!-- continue with the API invocation -->
    </else>
</filter>
```